# TypeScript, com ou sem ponto e virgula?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estou recentemente entrando no mundo angular, e me deparei com alguns tutoriais onde nem mesmo importações e também os códigos estão sem finalização seguido de `;`

Realmente se torna necessário a utilização?

E qual a diferença entre usar e não usar?

Comment: A pergunta é sobre JavaScript ou TypeScript?

Comment: A principio seria sobre os dois, pois possuem características de ambas as linguagens, tendo em vista que estou utilizando ts, porém a mesma tem como base js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na teoria, a obrigatoriedade do ponto e vírgula existe em um unico cenário, que é quando a próxima linha começar com um dos seguintes símbolos:

- `[`
- `(`
- `

Por exemplo:

```
var x = { xx : "hello", yy : "world"}
(function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
})();
```

Seguindo a regra, a segunda linha começa com um `(`, então, é obrigatorio o uso do `;` no final da primeira / inicio da segunda, ficando assim:

```
 var x = { xx : "hello", yy : "world"};
(function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
})();
```

O motivo da existência do ponto e virgula nesse cenário é um tanto quanto complexo, e bem abordado nesse  [artigo](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding).

Portanto, é possível, na maioria das vezes, simplesmente ignorar o ponto e vírgula no final das sentenças.

Porém, quando falamos de [coding standarts](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp), o recomendado é utilizar o `;` sempre que se for necessário.

Eu, particularmente, adoto o padrão de sempre colocar o `;`, quando cabível. Acredito que torna o código mais legível e padronizado.